# Boeing 787 Dreamliner Routes to Oceania?

Tags: airlines, routes, aircraft, boeing, oceania

I've looked into [pre-orders for the 787 Dreamliner](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/how-to-fly-on-the-new-boeing-787-dreamliner) before, but so many of them are delayed or not active or not on scheduled routes, I thought I'd ask here.

United was meant to have a route from Houston to Auckland, but that doesn't seem to have gone ahead as expected.

China Southern was alleged to have one from Guangzhou to Sydney, but that's not appearing anywhere either, as far as I can see.

**Is there a route from North America to Oceania (Australia or New Zealand) that uses the 787 for all or part of the journey?**

Comment: (wear asbestos and take a fire extinguisher)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this stage the only close-to-sensible 787 routes to Oceania (ie, excluding those that go via Europe/Africa!) are to go via Tokyo or (from April) Shanghai.

ANA currently flies between Seattle and Tokyo Narita, and will start flying from San Jose (California) to Tokyo Narita this Friday (Jan 11, 2013).

United Airlines currently flies between Los Angeles and Tokyo Narita and is due to start both Denver to Narita and Los Angeles to Shanghai in the last few days of March.

JAL flies between Boston Logan and Tokyo Narita, and started flying between San Diego and Narita a few days ago.

United is also flying a number of it's 787 on domestic routes, including to San Francisco and Los Angeles, so you could potentially book one of those flights at the end of flight to Australia/NZ out of LAX/SFO.  A few days ago I flew LAX-IAH on one, and despite being a relatively short trip I highly recommend - at least if you're sitting in First class :)

Answer (score 2):

[Qantas has just confirmed](http://www.ausbt.com.au/qantas-pumps-100m-into-boeing-787-rollout) that they're getting 787s, with Melbourne being the 'Dreamliner capital' of Australia.

> Popular routes from Sydney, Melbourne and Perth to the Gold Coast and
>   Cairns are on the cards, although Jetstar has yet to make a final call
>   on the 787's launch routes.