# British Airways Inaugural Flights

Tags: air-travel, lhr, british-airways

I can see when British Airways will inaugurate a new line of flying on [this page](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/flights-and-holidays/flights/new-routes#newroutes). But what about the inauguration of a new aircraft? I would expect these to be out of Heathrow owing to the huge pilot training centre there, but how can a person be among the first passengers to book and fly? Surely by the time an entry appears on the Wikipedia it's too late to book the inaugural flight?

There's a question in the archives here [How to fly on the new Boeing 787 Dreamliner?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/how-to-fly-on-the-new-boeing-787-dreamliner) which discusses some of the ways to find out, but it's nearly five years old and I'm interested in more than just the Dreamliner.

Comment: Do you mean a new model of aircraft, which is a pretty rare and significant event, or any new individual aircraft of a model BA already flies?

Comment: @ZachLipton a new model

Comment: You can check the manufacturers' websites for deliveries. Here's the page for [Boeing](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/#/orders-deliveries), and this page is for [Airbus](http://www.airbus.com/company/market/orders-deliveries/). If you get an estimate date it will be easy to track when exactly the first flight's date.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Information pertaining to BA fleet additions is summarized here: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1476013-ba-fleet-new-aircraft-arrivals-retirements-master-tracker.html (You need to click on the javascript link to expand the full wiki). The next aircraft scheduled for delivery is G-ZBKG in August.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The next BA aircraft to come into service will be the A350, estimated in service in [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Airbus_A350_XWB_orders_and_deliveries). This aircraft will supposedly feature a new club world (business class) offering of which there is much speculation going on over on [flyertalk](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1770289-new-club-world-genuinely-something-new.html).

For the A380 and B787, the first passenger ['training' flights](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1474630-new-aircraft-training-flights-b787-stockholm-a380-frankfurt.html) were flown on short haul routes. I would imagine the same will happen for the A350, but I expect it's too early to know yet.

BA had an A350 at their open day last year, but it was just stock/demo Airbus layout rather than BA livery and seating.

If you wish to be on the inaugural flights, the BA forum on FT is the place to find out when and where.

The other main resource is for BA aircraft and movements is [thebasource](http://www.thebasource.com/).